# Adding user to a group - Why had to reboot?

Tags: permissions

I was not able to access the VirtualBox shared folder, so I made the user part of the vboxsf group. But, still not able to access it. Rebooting the guest resolved the problem. Is it a bug? A reboot is not required to add a user to a group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf praveensripati
```

There was similar query [here](https://superuser.com/questions/307853/permission-denied-when-accessing-virtualbox-shared-folder-when-member-of-the-vbo/307860#307860).

I am using 11.10 and don't remember seeing similar behavior in 11.04.

Comment: thanks for posting above. I was having the same issue and did not think to reboot!! Still a bug but atleast i now know that rebooting solves the problem :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After making modifications to the groups of an user, the changes are not immediately visible. You need to re-login for that (which is accomplished with a reboot as well).

You can test which you belong to with the `id -Gn` command. After adding yourself to a random group, you'll notice that the group is not immediately visible in the output of that command. If you do not want to restart the graphical session ("re-login"), perform a direct login:

```
su - $USER
```

Enter your password and you'll be logged in with the new group settings applied. From there, start `virtualbox` and try it again. Note that you'll have to keep the console open now (unless using `screen`) so it might be easier to re-login.

Comment: Tiny note: you don't need to re-login to be part of the group: calling `newgr vboxsf`, after the `adduser USER vboxsf` (or `usermod`, as used in the question) will let you join the group.

Comment: @invernizzi I think you meant `newgrp`. It looks like a new shell is opened (similar to `su`), but without having to enter a password. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Big WARNING: With Ubuntu 20.X a Logout seems not to be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing the UID and GID to the mount command? Like this:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 sharedfolder mountPoint
```