# Why is "usermod -a -G" not adding my user to the group?

Tags: permissions, groups

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.  I want to add my user, "davea" to the group "www-data".  I tried this

```
(venv) davea@chicommons-laboratory:/var/www/html/web$ groups
davea sudo
(venv) davea@chicommons-laboratory:/var/www/html/web$ sudo usermod -a -G www-data davea
[sudo] password for davea: 
(venv) davea@chicommons-laboratory:/var/www/html/web$ groups
davea sudo
```

but as you can see, even though the command didn't give any errors, my user is still not added to the group.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding user to a group - Why had to reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69221/adding-user-to-a-group-why-had-to-reboot)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your command is good.
you can check the group with

```
getent group | grep davea
```

if your user are in group www-data, you just have to relog your user davea.

regards

Answer (score 6):

You need to log off and on the `davea` user to see that `davea` is a member of `www-data` group.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use  newgrp

From manpage

> The newgrp command is used to change the current group ID during a login session. If the optional - flag is given, the user's environment will be reinitialized as though the user had logged in, otherwise the current environment, including current working directory, remains unchanged.

```
newgrp - www-data
```

I use this in Live-sessions; where you usually you can not logput for reloging.